# Using facebook sdk alongside android app and web server

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I am looking to implement the Facebook login SDK for my android app and will be asking permissions for user friend list. However most of my background work happens on my web server and I communicate with my app via volley. I am wondering whether I can get the friend list via the web server once the user grants permission on my app or do I have to get the friend list through my app and send it to the server.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the user access token to your server and request the friend list on your server.

```
$session = new FacebookSession('access-token-here');
$friends = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'GET', '/me/friends'
))->execute()->getGraphObjectList(GraphUser::className());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do i need to add any authentication code on the php side or can i start querying the graph straight away?

Comment: You can just start making Graph API calls. I've updated my answer with an example for the PHP SDK. Put the access token you get into 'access-token-here' https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/

Comment: Thanks for your help. This will definately help